# Auto reconectar reusando uma conexão de socket async

Tags: c#, socket, async

Como faço para que meu socket se reconecte sozinho quando a conexão for perdida? De preferência reusando a mesma conexão.

Comment: Poste o código para facilitar a resposta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mantenha o código que cria a conexão dentro de um loop infinito `while(true){ Código aqui }`assim que você detectar que o socket caiu, insira uma instrução `continue` fazendo com que o código volte ao início do loop, reiniciando a conexão. Quando quiser de fato parar e fechar a conexão, insira uma instrução `break` para sair do loop e chegar nos códigos de finalização do método

Como você não informou o código que está usando vou fazer um exemplo fictício abaixo:

```
public void InfiniteSocket(String host, Int32 port) {
    var ipe = new IPEndPoint(host, port);
    var soc = new Socket(ipe.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    while(true) {
        try {
            soc.Connect(ipe);
            if(!soc.Connected) //se não conectar, tenta novamente
                continue;
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            //Algo deu errado com o endereço/porta
            break; //aborta o loop
        }
        //Boolean ConversaComSocket(Socket socket)
        //A função ConversaComSocket retorna true caso tudo tenha ocorrido bem (pode encerrar o socket) ou false caso tenha detectado que a conexão caiu!
        var podeFinalizar = ConversaComSocket(soc);
        if(!podeFinalizar)
            continue; //volta ao inicio do loop e reabre conexão
        soc.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
        soc.Close();
        break; //sai do loop
    }        
}
```